# Ubuntu 15.10 Chrome launch problem

Tags: google-chrome, 15.10, browser

Hi I am newbie in linux (ubuntu) and have some problem with chrome

downloaded chrome
and can't launch chrome-browser.
how to solve this?

this is error:

```
$ google-chrome-stable
[1130/235040:ERROR:nss_util.cc(96)] Failed to create /home/vakho/.pki/nssdb directory.
[1130/235040:ERROR:nss_util.cc(96)] Failed to create /home/vakho/.pki/nssdb directory.
[4772:4806:1130/235040:ERROR:nss_util.cc(96)] Failed to create /home/vakho/.pki/nssdb directory.
[4772:4772:1130/235040:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(419)] readlink failed: Permission denied
[4772:4772:1130/235040:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(255)] readlink(/home/vakho/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[4772:4772:1130/235040:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(255)] readlink(/home/vakho/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[4772:4772:1130/235040:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(279)] Failed to create /home/vakho/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Permission denied
[4772:4772:1130/235040:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(419)] readlink failed: Permission denied
[4772:4772:1130/235040:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(255)] readlink(/home/vakho/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[4772:4772:1130/235040:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1291)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to also include the output of the following command: `ls -al ~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you messed around with `sudo` where you should not have done and therefore the owner of some folders in your home directory are wrong.

If my guess is correct, simply executing the command

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```

from a terminal (open one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) on your own account should fix it.

---

Otherwise please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/704374/edit) your question and add the output of the terminal command

```
ls -la ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Comment: I think you're right.