# Re-launch Chrome from a guest account

Tags: 16.04, permissions, google-chrome, crash, guest-session

Chrome crashed while I had a few tabs open, on a guest account with Ubuntu 16.04.

I want to re-launch Chrome before signing out of this guest account, so that I can get my tabs back, before signing out of the guest account and losing any unsaved data, such as the records of what tabs were open.

However double clicking the Chrome icon, doesn't launch Chrome anymore. Launching from a terminal doesn't seem to work either:

```
guest-maovuu@alavi:~$ google-chrome
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Process org.freedesktop.secrets exited with status 1
```

The terminal prompt has not even returned, and pressing CTRL+C just prints `^C` and doesn't actually return me to being able to type commands again.

Strangely, the resource manager says that several Chrome processes are running:

[image]

But if I right click them and press "kill", I get (for each PID):

```
Cannot kill process with PID 15882 with signal 9.
Permission denied
```

I tried the following kill commands from the command line but 3 of them did nothing and 1 gave a permission denied error:

```
guest-maovuu@alavi:~$ kill 15882
guest-maovuu@alavi:~$ pkill  15882
guest-maovuu@alavi:~$ pkill -9 15882
guest-maovuu@alavi:~$ kill -9 15882
bash: kill: (15882) - Permission denied
```

I tried with sudo, but perhaps it doesn't work because I'm using a guest account (?):

```
guest-maovuu@alavi:~$ sudo pkill -9 15882
sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I've looked at all relevant previous questions here that I could find but they all seem outdated or don't relate to the problem I'm having:

- [Chrome won't start from the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/418295/676348)
- [Ubuntu 15.10 Chrome launch problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/704374/676348)
- [Unable to launch chrome - Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/724830/676348)
- [Chrome will not launch](https://askubuntu.com/q/956309/676348)

I had a lot of tabs open, so it would be nice if I can launch Chrome back and click "restore old tabs", since I don't remember what they all were. If I can't do that, I would like to be able to get my tabs back somehow, if they are stored in some file, but I'm still curious how to re-launch Chrome without signing out of the Guest account.